# pdfcomment with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, pdfcomment, tooltips

It seems, `\pdftooltip` (pdfcomment) does not work with LuaLaTeX, at least, this does not seem to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \pdftooltip
    {The international metric system of units or dimensions is used in electricity.}
    {This tooltip cannot be seen.}
\end{document}
```

I checked with the builtin pdf-viewer in firefox as well as evince, which are both able to display tool tips in other documents. The same document compiled with pdflatex does work.

Comment: works ok for me in adobe reader, perhaps evince can't handle the utf8 string.

Comment: Worked for me with Sumatra PDF viewer. Compiled by LuaTex 1.12.0

Comment: Evince doesn't support this kind of annotations (regardless of which LaTeX compiler you use). See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/882. Apparently there is a fix, which unfortunately is not available yet for mere mortals (https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/842).

Comment: With Okular and OpenSuSe it fails as well. But clicking on the text it displays poorly something although only when forms are enabled. Just would be curios how to fix this issue...